# C# WPF - How to change a textblock when you press a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make it currently so that when i press lets say Button1 a textblock will change to a specific value. How i am trying to do this is like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textResult.Text = currentValue.ToString();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentValue = 1;
    }
```

textResult is the textblock.

If i launch my program however it does not change.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Make use of Binding, the Text property of the textblock with the currentValue property,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentValue = 1;
        textResult.Text = currentValue.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting your TextBox's text property so you must do like as follow:-

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentValue = 1;
        textResult.Text = currentValue.ToString();
    }
```